# 3Sum on Leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm working on the [3sum problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum). I did it by sorting the array in the beginning and then using two pointer method to find all the unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

My question is that if I comment out the two while loops at the end, the runtime can be improved from 32ms to 26ms. I get a 6 ms speed boost. I think the time complexity is still O(n^2). Does anyone know why commenting out the while loops is faster?

```
public List<List<Integer>> threeSum(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
    if(nums.length < 3){
        return result;
    }

    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.length - 1;
    int threeSum = 0;

    Arrays.sort(nums);

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 2 && nums[i] <= 0; i ++) {
        right = nums.length - 1;
        if (i > 0) {
            while (i < right && nums[i - 1] == nums[i])
                 i ++;
        }
        left = i + 1;

        while (left < right) {
            threeSum = nums[i] + nums[left] + nums[right];                
            if (threeSum == 0) {
                result.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[left], nums[right]));
                left ++;
                right --;
                while (left < right && nums[left - 1] == nums[left])
                    left ++;
                while (left < right && nums[right + 1] == nums[right])
                    right --;
            } else if (threeSum < 0) {
                // move to the right
                left ++;
                // Skip duplicate numbers
                // Comment this out get 6 ms speed increase
                while (left < right && nums[left - 1] == nums[left])
                    left ++;
            } else {
                right --;
                // Skip duplicate numbers
                // Comment this out get 6 ms speed increase
                while (left < right && nums[right + 1] == nums[right])
                    right --;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: There's no way to give a useful answer. This is essentially a micro-benchmark, and such are notoriously sensitive to minor variations that have nothing to do with the goodness of the algorithm.

Comment: timings in the low ms range are not useful for profiling the runtime at all. They vary even from test run to test run. So before any further investigaion, profile with a much larges input to get stable timings.

Comment: If we assume the benchmarks are correct, then it would just tell us that for your test input the overhead of the two loops is bigger than the gain. Although you would have to do many different tests of varying sizes and number distributions to say anything meaningful.